# How to print a table with Javascript, and no DOM interaction

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small program to output a table like this:
**(This is what I want!)**
[image]

This is my (incorrect) code so far:

```
var daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu']
var time = ['9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm', '1pm', '2pm'];

for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  console.log("     "+daysOfWeek.join('  '));
   for (j = 0; j < time.length; j++ ) {
     if ((time[j] === '9am' || time[j] === '2pm') && (daysOfWeek[i] === 'Mon')) {
      console.log(time[j], 'Bowser');
     } else {
       console.log(time[j]);
     }
  }
}
```

This is the output I'm receiving from my code:

[image]

I don't know how to log Maggie in the first column, and I don't know how to 
traverse the chart to add Fifi and Spike. Also, my code is really messy...

Can someone help me find a clean, efficient way to print out the table?

Comment: Why do you need a loop `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)`. That just runs once, it doesn't actually loop.

Comment: Good point, I don't need one.

Comment: One thing you're missing from this assignment: "Define a data structure to model this data". In any case, I expect the intent is that you figure this out for yourself, not farm the work out to volunteers.

Comment: As @MikeMcCaughan said. You need a way to map 10 AM Monday to  "Bowser" and 2PM to "Maggie"... Once you define that data structure, you can iterate to print information. As of now that does not exist. Try using a object model to store data.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't my intent to make other do work for me. Rather, I misunderstood the question then. I'll be more mindful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a data structure that holds the dog walking schedule. You can use nested objects:

```
var schedule = {
    Mon: {
        '10am': 'Bowser',
        '2pm': 'Maggie'
    },
    Tue: {
        '11am': 'Fifi'
    },
    Wed: {
        '12pm': 'Spike'
    },
    'Thu': {
    }
}
```

Then your loop can match each time slot with what's in the schedule.

```
console.log("\t"+daysOfWeek.join('\t'));
for (j = 0; j < times.length; j++) {
    line = times[j];
    for (i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
        if (schedule[daysOfWeek[i]][times[j]]) {
            lines += "\t" + schedule[daysOfWeek[i]][times[j]];
        } else {
            lines += "\t\t";
        }
    }
    console.log(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu']
var time = ['9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm', '1pm', '2pm'];

var people = [{
    name: "Bowser",
    time: "9am",
    day: "Mon"
  }, {
    name: "Maggie",
    time: "12pm",
    day: "Mon"
  },

  {
    name: "George",
    time: "1pm",
    day: "Wed"
  },

];
var days = pad("");
for (var i in daysOfWeek) {
  days += pad(daysOfWeek[i]);
}
console.log(days);
for (var j in time) {

  var line = pad(time[j]);
  for (var i in daysOfWeek) {
    var p = getPersonAt(time[j], daysOfWeek[i]);
    if (p != null) {
      line += pad(p.name);
    } else {
      line += (pad(""));
    }
  }
  console.log(line);
}

function getPersonAt(time, day) {
  for (var i in people) {
    if (people[i].time == time && people[i].day == day) {
      return people[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function pad(str) {
  while (str.length < 15) {
    str = str + " ";
  }
  return str;
}
```

I created a fiddle where I printed the result to html.

I created objects with name/time/day value and I iterated through all the time and days and when both matched (getPersonAt returned an object) I printed the name of the object.

The pad function pads the string but needs adjustment if the names are longer than 15 characters.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qotm56z/1/)

Comment: I misunderstood that the dogs are being walked so the array is named people ^^

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.